# IR/R could not detect when using landsat 8 in ERDAS 2014 Is there a alternative way around?

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, digital-image-processing, landsat-8, multi-band

I'm using ERDAS 2014 and I upgraded from ERDAS 2013.

I am doing a lot of band indices for various kinds of such as clay, ferrous, Mineral composite and so on.. from landsat 8.

Using the indices in ERDAS 2014, the problem is that it does not detect IR/R (infrared divided by red) if you change the sensor to Landsat 8 MS but if you look at other landsat such as 4 TM and 5 TM.

I can see that the formula for IR/R is IR/ Red which is Band 5 / Band 4. This band is for Landsat 8.

OR would I have to take a BAND 5 and BAND 4 separately and run the formula in ERDAS ?

Anybody have that same problem ?

**Edit:**

Recall this is a landsat 8 and there should be a list for IR/R but I do not find one.

Your thoughts ?

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide more details on the source of your imagery?  What image format are you using? Did you stack the raster bands yourself?

Comment: Yes, I use landsat 8 bands and stacked 7 bands and bring them to ERDAS 2014. On the Classification list and use the indices dialog box and under the Index Options I do not find IR/R on the list ?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the "Indices" GUI with your landsat scene loaded (i.e. Raster > Unsupervised > Indices)?  Also, how many spectral bands are in your raster stack?

Comment: Do you have that Landsat 8 OLI on your ERDAS 2014 or 2015 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the "Show All" box in the Index Options GUI.

[image]

Comment: BINGO !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! dang !